# Adding customer multiselect attribute

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add a multiselect attribute to magento 2 customers. It works perfectly when adding text / input value, but cannot figure how to add multiselect. Here is my code :

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allowed_brands', [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Allowed brands',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'option' =>
          array (
            'values' =>
            array (
              'Option 1',
              'Option 2',
              'Option 3',
              'Option 4',
            ),
          ),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allowed_brands', [
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Allowed brands',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'required' => false,
    'visible' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'position' => 1000,
    'system' => 0,
    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
    'source' => 'YourVendor\YourExtension\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AllowedBrands'
]);
```

Create the AllowedBrands class at:

> app/code/YourVendor/YourExtension/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/AllowedBrands.php

With these contents:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourExtension\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class AllowedBrands extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ],
            'option3' => [
                'label' => 'Option 3',
                'value' => 'option3'
            ],
            'option4' => [
                'label' => 'Option 4',
                'value' => 'option4'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! (I only found "position" and "sort_order" to be not working on "addAttribute", only on "updateAttribute", but that's the same with Magento 1)

Comment: can you please explain this line little, Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz, Can we see this attribute in admin? Once created how to assign the value for customer address programmatically?

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz, I successfully created the attribute using above code.

Comment: @jafarpinjar Either $customerAddress->setData('allowed_brands', $value); or $customerAddress->setCustomAttribute('allowed_brands', $value); should work for setting the value programmatically.

Comment: Its not working for me, tried both the ways..

Comment: I have applied changes from above but values are not saved. any one have an idea ?

Answer (score -3):

You don't need either 'array' under 'option'. The square brackets around the values indicate it is an array. Set it like this:

```
     $eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Customer::ENTITY,
     'allowed brands',
     [
     'type' => 'text',
     'label' => 'Available Brands',
     'input' => 'multiselect',
     'required' => false, (etc)

     'option' => [
            'values' => [
                    'Option 1',
                    'Option 2',
                    'Option 3',
                    'Option 4'
                    ]
                ]
    ]
    );
```

Comment: I understand, but the result is the same.

Comment: correct, but that is not motive to vote down... I thinks so...