# Magento 2 : Sorting Customer Attributes Option Array

Tags: magento2, customer, sorting, customer-attribute, select

I used these posts: 
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html

[Adding customer multiselect attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117344/adding-customer-multiselect-attribute)

For creating a custom customer attribute select list. This is working but I would like to have select list ordered **alphabetical** because of length of list. Any ideas on how to pull this? I need to be able to assing a label and attribute for select options, such as:

```
class AllowedBrands extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
{
    return [
        'option1' => [
            'label' => 'Univé',
            'value' => '13232'
        ],
        'option2' => [
            'label' => 'Achmea',
            'value' => '3121199999'
        ],
        'option3' => [
            'label' => 'Zeker',
            'value' => '9274'
        ]
    ];
    }
}
```

But how to make sure they are ordered alphabetical?

Comment: No I do not think this is duplicate, this question is regarding the ordering (alphabetical) of the select options.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below,

```
$optionArray = [ 'option1' => [ 'label' => 'Univé', 'value' => '13232' ], 'option2' => [ 'label' => 'Achmea', 'value' => '3121199999' ], 'option3' => [ 'label' => 'Zeker', 'value' => '9274' ] ];

function sortByName($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]); 
} 
usort($optionArray , "sortByName");
return $optionArray;
```